# Facebook authentication by ionic cloud

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework, ionic2

[The photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1UKZ.jpg)Has anyone done facebook authentication using ionic cloud before?
Why is my signup  false?

```
this.loginDetails = await this.facebook.login();
console.log(this.loginDetails);
```

The signup turns out false.

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43372265/1077309

Comment: Nope it didnt work